# A js file changes links' color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I made this website: http://galant-jeans.x10.mx
As you can see, if you hover on them, and then get away, they turn blue.
This is not mentioned on css, but it should be on the menu.js file.
The problem is that I can't find it.
Here is the link to the .js file : http://galant-jeans.x10.mx/js/menu.js

Comment: Try to make your question useful to future readers by including relevant source code and/or a test case. The moment you edit or move the files you linked to, this thread has no value.

Comment: +1 to Madmartigan, I have never thought about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suspecting this construct in menu.js:

```
if ( fx.start )
                fx.elem.style[attr] = "rgb(" + [
                    Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[0] - fx.start[0])) + fx.start[0]), 255), 0),
                    Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[1] - fx.start[1])) + fx.start[1]), 255), 0),
                    Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[2] - fx.start[2])) + fx.start[2]), 255), 0)
                ].join(",") + ")";
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, I just changed a number there, and it isn't working anymore.
I mean the script works, but the color doesn't change.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug! It shows that there is a `div#menu a:hover` entry in index.css on line 112 which changes the background.

Comment: I tried that, but it seems that the menu.js adds properties to that element.

Comment: Yes it gets overridden by an inline style on the links